# Why is the first derivative of $y = \frac{dy}{dx}$ and not $\frac{dx}{dy}$?

Tags: calculus

This is how I tried to figure it out:

$y=x$

now we take differentiate both sides:

$y' * dy = dx$

$y' = \frac{dx}{dy}$

But in all examples my professor did, $y'$ was equal to $\frac{dy}{dx}$, without any explanation. Why? I'm solving problems about differential equations. Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get $y=x$ from? If that were true, then both $dy/dx$ and $dx/dy$ would simply be $1$.

Comment: Well, in this case, $y'=1$, so $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dx}{dy}$.

Comment: This is how I tried to figure it out: $y=x$ now we take differentiate both sides: $y' * dy = dx$ Where did you get this? It is NOT correct.

Comment: You are doing implicit differentiantion when it is not nescessary.  You are doing  y = x so so "derivative of y in terms of x" = "derivative of y in terms of y" times "derivative of y in terms of x".  Or "$y'_x = y'_y*dy/dx$ which is not wrong.  But as "derivative of y in terms of y" is 1 you don't need to do implicit differentiation... and it never even occured to your professor that anyone would consider it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $y=f(x)$.  Then $$\begin{matrix} y' && f'(x) && f' && \frac{dy}{dx} \\ \frac{d}{dx}y && \frac{df(x)}{dx} && \frac{df}{dx}(x) && \left.\frac{df}{dx}\right|_x \\ Dy && D_xy && Df && D_xf \\ Df(x) && (Df)(x) && D_xf(x) &&(D_xf)(x)\end{matrix}$$ are ALL different commonly used ways writing the derivative of the function $f$ at $x$.  There is no difference between them$^\dagger$ because each is simply a different notation for the same concept.

The reason the notation $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a good one is that $$y' = \frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{(x+h)-x} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\Delta f(x,h)}{\Delta x(h)} \approx \frac{\Delta f}{\Delta x}$$ where that approximation in the last part holds if $h$ is small enough.  So the notation $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is supposed to remind you of that fact.  Plus it works particularly nicely with the chain rule.

---

**Interpretation of Your Question #1**

Now that we see that $y'$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}$ are the same **by definition**, let's see what's wrong with your work.

First off, why do you assume that because $y = y(x)$ that $y=x$?  That's only one possible function that $y$ could be.

Your second mistake comes when using differentials.  Differentials are a little bit different from the above because in the Leibniz notation, $\frac{dy}{dx}$, the $dy$ and $dx$ are not independent objects -- they are  just parts of the notation.  But the differentials $dx$ and $dy$ **are** separate objects. The formula you should memorize (for now -- you'll learn more about it later) for differentials is if $y=f(x)$ then $dy=f'(x)dx$.  So using this we see that $f'(x) = \frac{dy}{dx}$ where $dx$ and $dy$ are differentials in this particular equation, not just parts of the notation for the derivative -- this equation is why we use the notation $dx$ and $dy$ for differentials.

Now if you did mean to specifically choose the function $y=x$ specifically, then $$dy=y'dx = 1dx \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = 1 = y'$$

---

**Interpretation of Your Question #2**

Maybe you're just trying to confirm that there are no inconsistencies with implicit differentiation and the implicit function theorem by trying them out on some easy functions.  OK.  Then if we say that $y = f(y)$ and (using the implicit function theorem) that $x=x(y)$ then $$y=x \implies f'(y)dy = dx$$  So you're right that $f'(y) = \frac{dx}{dy}\ \left(= 1\right)$.  That is, the *derivative of $y$ with respect to $y$* is the derivative of the function $x(y) = y$.  Note that using this exact same approach -- but taking the derivative with respect to $x$ on both sides -- you can also see that $y'(x) = \frac{dy}{dx}$, as we'd expect.

---

$^\dagger$: Technically speaking there is (or at least *should be*) a subtle difference between symbols like $f'(x)$ and $f'$.  The first denotes a number while the second denotes a function.  However it is a common abuse of notation to either one with whichever meaning is evident from context.

Comment: +1 for actually explaining to the OP what the concepts really mean.

Answer (score 6):

It's written as $\frac{dy}{dx}$ because we're taking the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$, ak.a.

$$\frac{d}{dx}(y)$$

Answer (score 3):

The notation $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is analogous to the notation $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ for the slope of secant lines (or straight lines). Think "rise over run." The notation is meant to be reminiscent of the secant line slope formula; nothing more, nothing less. However if you consider the *very special* case of $y(x) = x$ (i.e. a straight line), if you take the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ you get $y'(x) = 1$. **However** you can also view $x$ as a function of $y$ a la $x(y) = y$ (this is because it is a straight line of slope $1$) in which case $\frac{dx}{dy} = x'(y) = 1$.

This is a very special case and does not hold true in general. To see that this is indeed the case, consider $y(x) = 2x$. What is $y'(x)$? What is $x'(y)$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $y = g(x)$

Let $f(y)$ be a function of y.

Then the derivative of $f(y)$ with *respect to x* is $f'(y)y'$ or $ = \dfrac{df(y)}{dy}*\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{df(y)}{dy}*\dfrac{dg(x)}{dx}$.

[The derivative of $f(y)$ with *respect to y* is simply $f'(y)$.  Nothing more to it.]

This is implicit differentiation when you have a compound function.

But if you have a simple non-compound function

$y = g(x)$

That's it, you don't have a further function of y, You don't have to do implicit differentiate as there is nothing implicit to differentiate.

You just do

$y = g(x)$ so $y' = g'(x) = \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dg(x)}{dx}$  That's it.

Now you *could* do implicit differentiation by saying

$y = g(x)$ and $f(y) = y$

So $f(y)'_x = \dfrac{df(y)}{dy}*\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ but as $\dfrac{df(y)}{dy} = 1$ that's a pointless extra step.

So with $y = x$ you are attempting to do $Y = y = x$ (*the capital Y is my introduction; it is to clarify your thought processes-- you were attempting the same but you wrote it as a lower case y which would have made my explanation a bit ... opaque*) and $\dfrac{dY}{dx} = Y'*\dfrac{dy}{dx}$.  As $Y = y$ means $Y' = 1$ this extra step is unnecessary and wouldn't even occur to most people to even consider.

After all we can infinitely derive $y = f(x)$ so the derivative is $\dfrac{dy}{dy}\dfrac{dy}{dy}\dfrac{dy}{dy}\dfrac{dy}{dy}\dfrac{dy}{dy}...\dfrac{dy}{dy}\dfrac{dy}{dx}$.

Which is kind of silly.